# How to track http referrer across post back?

Tags: asp.net

I have a page in my website that can be reached from several other pages.  On this page I have a cancel button and when people click that I would like to execute some code on the server and then redirect back to the page they came from.

I was trying to do this by referencing Request.UrlReferrer, but once a post back occurs, this is set to the current page.

I have come up with a workaround using session state:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
          Session["referrer"] = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
    }
}

btn_Cancel_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Some other code and then the line below:
    Response.Redirect(Session["referrer"]);
}
```

But I'm curious if there is a more graceful way to do this without using session state.  Can anyone suggest a better solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UrlReferrer` is not safe to be used for return back with the cancel because many users can ether select to block it (and not giving information's from where they have come from), and also I have see some times that malicious programs place there spam sites.

The correct way is to use a parameter on the url that tell to your page where to return on cancel - eg:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/callpage.aspx?ref=/signin/
```